# laravel relationship backwards

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have a test site where I've got a `recipes`, `ingredients`, and `ingredient_uses` tables. Each recipe "uses" ingredients in different quantities and prepared differently (eg. chopped, sliced, minced, grated), so the `ingredient_uses` table tracks the `recipe_id` and the `ingredient_id` with the other variable info.

The relationships look like this:

**Recipe model:**

```
public function ingredients()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Ingredient', 'App\IngredientUse');
}

public function ingredientUses()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\IngredientUse');
}
```

**Ingredient_Use model:**

```
public function ingredient()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Ingredient');
}

public function recipe()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Recipe');
}
```

**Ingredient model:**

```
public function recipe()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredient');
}
```

I thought I wanted a `hasManyThrough` relationship from the recipe to the ingredient table, using the ingredient_uses as the middle table. But the sql is wrong:

```
SELECT `ingredients`.*, `ingredient_uses`.`recipe_id` 
FROM `ingredients`
INNER JOIN `ingredient_uses`
    ON `ingredient_uses`.`id` = `ingredients`.`ingredient_use_id` 
WHERE `ingredient_uses`.`recipe_id` = 1
```

This is what I think I want:

```
SELECT `ingredients`.*, `ingredient_uses`.`recipe_id`
FROM `ingredients` 
INNER JOIN `ingredient_uses`
    ON `ingredient_uses`.`ingredient_id` = `ingredients`.`id` 
WHERE `ingredient_uses`.`recipe_id` = 1
```

Is there a more appropriate relationship that I should be using?

Comment: Wait - I thought `Ingredient_Use` should `belongsTo` Ingredient? Why it's hasOne? :)

Comment: i think u should use belongsToMany in Ingredient  model, https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 2):

First thing - you don't need Ingredient_Use model. Model examples:

```
class Ingredient extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'ingredients';

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function recipes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class, 'recipes_ingredients', 'ingredient_id');
    }
}




class Recipe extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'recipes';

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class, 'recipes_ingredients', 'recipe_id')->withPivot('additional', 'fields');
    }
}
```

Access to additional fields example

```
$recipe->pivot->additional;
```

Answer (score 0):

in **Ingredient**  model

```
class Ingredient extends Model
{


    public function recipe(){

          return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class, 'ingredient_uses', 'ingredient_id', 'recipe_id');
    }

}
```

other models will be empty thats mean there would not be any function inside Recipe model and Ingredient model .

u can see documentation about this
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many